# Using the host option for routes on my local machine

Tags: symfony, routes, subdomain

Given this route

```
m:
    pattern:  /
    host:     m.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Default:index }
```

It fails on my local machine as it rewrite to the live domain rather than my local machine.

Is there a way of having this work on my local machine and the live environment without having to rewrite the whole of my routing file for my dev environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must refactor the host out to your `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    domain: m.example.com
```

The in your routing:

```
m:
    pattern:  /
    host:     %domain%
    defaults: { _controller: Bundle:Default:index }
```

For your dev environment simply change the domain parameter in your `parameters.yml`.

Comment: Thanks @Pazi I went for a similar approach, but instead created a dev parameters.yml file with a different domain in for dev. That way I can use the same routes without having to rewrite each one for dev. I have a lot you see.